# Custom WP permalink structure

Tags: permalinks

I've been struggling trying to wrap my brain around this problem for a few hours. I'm basically trying to achieve this URL structure for a coupon site I run.

`http://www.mysite.com/store/walmart/coupon-1`

Each coupon is a WP post and the default structure for it now is.

`http://www.mysite.com/coupon-1`

The `store` text is static and if that was the only prefix I needed for a coupon I could easily go into Settings -> Permalink and setup something like this `/store/%postname%/` but since the store name is dynamic ... well you see my problem.

I've started off approaching the problem by doing what I know and using a RewriteRule in .htaccess (ex: `RewriteRule ^store/(.*)/(.*)$ $2 [R=301,L]`) but that didn't give me the right result, it would just redirect to the original URL structure.

I've found a couple articles on the topic but they're either poorly explained or just refer to a simple redirect. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer I can think of is to use what's already built in: categories.

If you know what stores you're going to have coupons for, create a category for each of them and assign that category to the post. You can then use a permalink structure like `/store/%category%/%postname%`.

Comment: Thats an excellent idea but its not going to work in my case unfortunately. I have a category section on the site that already uses that taxonomy so I have to leave categories alone. This might help someone else down the line though.